# Change SKTextureFilteringMode for all SKTextures

Tags: swift, swift3, sprite-kit, sktexture

Is there a way to assign the `filteringMode` attribute to `SKTextureFilteringMode.nearest` for ALL `SKTextures`? Other than assigning to each texture individually. The following works fine, but I'd rather that I didn't have to iterate over the textures, but just set a default for the filtering mode. Is this possible?

```
func walk () -> SKAction {

    let walkTexture1 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "walk1.png")
    let walkTexture2 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "walk2.png")
    let walkTexture3 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "walk3.png")
    let walkTexture4 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "walk4.png")
    let walkTexture5 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "walk5.png")


    let animationTextures: [SKTexture] = [walkTexture1, walkTexture2, walkTexture3, walkTexture4, walkTexture5]

    for texture in animationTextures {
        texture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.nearest
    }

    let walkAnimation = SKAction.animate(with: animationTextures, timePerFrame: 0.3/5)

    return walkAnimation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create textures and set properties in the same loop

`let textures = (1...5).map {
  let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "walk\($0).png")
  texture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.nearest
  return texture
}`

or just set properties using `forEach`

`textures.forEach {
  $0.filteringMode = .nearest
}`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps make an extension to SKTexture, something like this:

```
extension SKTexture {
    class func pixeled(imageNamed imageName: String) -> SKTexture {
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: imageName)
        texture.filteringMode = .nearest
        return texture
    }
}
```

Then you'll simply have

```
let walkTexture1 = SKTexture.pixeled(imageNamed: "walk1.png")
```

etc.